# Execute PHP script onclick with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello I'm struggling to get this to work:

I'm trying to get jQuery to execute a PHP Script for me, at the moment it looks pretty much like this:

html

```
<button id="element">Click me!</button>
```

php

```
$string = "Hello Earth!";
echo $string;
```

jQuery

```
$('#element').click(function() {
    $.load('.../script.php', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: Which part isn't working? Error messages?

Comment: That is not were the load function is for from the jQuery manual: Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Comment: the only error I have in my console is `ReferenceError: $ is not defined (test.html:11)` which is the line `$('#element').click(function() {`

Comment: That's a pretty important error :) It means that you haven't correctly imported jQuery, so absolutely none of your code will work.

Comment: Oh right I'm sorry I forgot to put it into my test script x)

now im getting: `TypeError: $.load is not a function`

Comment: oh dumb me... I did manage to mess up the path reference I did 3 dots "..." instead of 2 "..".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.load()` must be called on an element, like this:

```
$('#element').click(function() {
   $('#element').load('.../script.php', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The load() method loads data from a server and **puts the returned data into the selected element**. *from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp*

Correct sintax:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

And you have to correct your code, you have .../script.php instead of ../script.php

Comment: Question: Is it possible instead of replacing the content of my element, to append/prepend the value?

Comment: Shure.
Something like this example:
`code`$('#element').click(function() {
    $.get('retrieve.html', function(data, status){ // data is retrieve.html, then you can append/prepend it wherever you want
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
`code`

Comment: Is it possible with `.load`? I'd like to prevent to use get if I I'm not going to submit any value.

Comment: Also you seem to stuggle with the ´code´ tags `code`, just place them around your code like this: ´stuff´ => `stuff` (I used to reverted tags to display it)

And I just Googled a bit and found the solution here: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-but-append-data-instead-of-replace

Comment: Sorry about the tags.
Nice to hear you googled it. You could use it this way to:
$('#element').click(function() {
    $("#returnedResult").load("retrieve.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        console.log(responseTxt);
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="element">Click me!</button>
```

`<?php $string = "Hello Earth!"; 
    echo $string; ?>`

```
$('#element').live('click',function() {
 $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    success:fuction(data){
          'your coe here';
    }
 })
});
```