# HTML/PHP Page Structing to permanantly redirect to a different page

Tags: php, html, redirect, structure

I am trying this page structure to a part of my website but I cannot figure out how.
This is with a logged in user:

> On page 1, user clicks button to get themselves to page 2
>
> On page 2, user does OPERATION to get themselves to page 3

Now, I it will become:

> On page 1, user clicks button to get themselves to page 3

(as in, the same button that originally got them to page 2 before, but since the user did OPERATION, the button that normally leads them to 2, leads them to 3 permanantly)

Specifically what I need help with is getting page 1 to redirct to page 3 instead of 2 after OPERATION happens. How do I go about this? Probably something using databases I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to keep track of user's status in `$_SESSION` superglobal. Let me explain how.

When the user does an operation, records its status in session, like this:

```
$_SESSION['operation'] = true;
```

**page1.php**

```
if($_SESSION['operation']){
   // user has already completed the operation
   // redirect the user to page3.php
   header("Location: page3.php");
   exit();
}else{
   // user didn't complete the operation
   // redirect the user to page2.php
   header("Location: page2.php");
   exit();
}
```

**page2.php**

```
// when the user completes the operation, redirect the user to page3.php, like this
header("Location: page3.php");
exit();
```

Comment: Okay, I think I get what your saying. One question I have is, how do I make it so that when a button is pressed, operation is true?

Comment: You can use javascript to implement such behavior.

Comment: Ah. I have never used js before. Would you know of any guides for something like this?

Comment: I think this will help you, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587358/execute-php-script-onclick-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587358/execute-php-script-onclick-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

- Set a session variable to store whether the `operation` has been
  performed.
- The link to the button should be set dynamically based on session 
  variable

In your operation() do the following :

```
opertation()
{
//some stuff here
$_SESSION['op_done']=true;
}
```

In the button link

```
<a href="<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['op_done']) && $_SESSION['op_done'])
{
echo "link_to_page3";
}
else 
{
echo "link_to_page2";
}
?>"> Button_Name
</a>
```

In short, make a dynamic button link which will adjust with your session variable.

Comment: What I use to redirct someone if they're not logged in is: `session_start();

 if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) || empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
     die(header("Location: login.php")); 
    }
?>` so how would I modify that to get a variable in the database and redirect if true?

Comment: @Voken : Dynamic button link should be your solution. Please see the edit. It gives a general idea.